# How to locate Telerik controls in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, telerik

URL : 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dropdownlist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Question :
How to select dropdown value?

My Code:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='rddlSlide']//span")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Chai");
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to select dropdown value?

Actually target element is not proper `<select>` element, Hence you can't handle is using [`Select`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class.

Try as below :-

```
driver.get("http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dropdownlist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);

//This line would find the dropdown element and open the options
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceholder1_RadDropDownProducts"))).click();

//This line would select the desire option using their text
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[text() = 'Chai']"))).click();
```